# ClassNotFoundException glassfish servlet

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, glassfish, glassfish-5

So I am trying to set up a glassfish server using Intellij. It used to work but suddenly it doesn't work anymore. The error message I'm getting is "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test" (full stack trace at the bottom).

Edit: Not using maven.

The project structure looks like this:

[image]

The Test3.iml was auto generated, while I created test.Test.java and web.xml myself.

Test.java looks like this:

```
package test;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().write("Bla bla bla");
        resp.getWriter().close();
    }
}
```

web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.Test</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Finally, Test3.iml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="web" name="Web">
      <configuration>
        <webroots>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web" relative="/" />
        </webroots>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="GlassFish 5.0.0 - RESTful Web Service" level="application_server_libraries" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="GlassFish 5.0.0" level="application_server_libraries" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Full stack trace:

```
[2018-01-13T14:02:18.469+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1515848538469] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /]]

  WebModule[]Error loading WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) test.Test
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1431)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2018-01-13T14:02:18.480+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1515848538480] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[test]: Allocate exception for servlet test
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1431)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Comment: Are you using maven ?

Comment: @GregArtisi , no I am not.

Comment: Did you redeployed your application on glassfish?

Comment: Yes I tried that multiple times. Restarting the glassfish server as well.

Comment: That is Strange, it is trying to find the class in WEB-INF/classes/

Comment: In the output files the class Test.class is actually in the folder "web-inf/classes/test/"